# unset form submit button

Tags: php, html

```
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['vendor_add_submit'])){

//INSERT INTO DB

unset(  $_POST['vendor_add_submit'] );
}

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >


<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="vendor_email" value="" />


<input type="submit" name="vendor_add_submit" value="SAVE" />


</form>
</body>
```

`unset(  $_POST['vendor_add_submit'] );` is used to prevent more than one time insertion into db on page refresh. I tested with `print_r($_POST['vendor_add_submit'] )` before and after the unset and found that the `unset()` function does not work.

How can I achieve the purpose of the unset function, plz?

Comment: @evolve 2 , ok i'll take care

Comment: yes that's what it means, picking the green checkmark next to the right answer for your questions.. see your profile for a list of questions, most do not have accepted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unset isn't going to stop the refresh from being able to replay the POSTed data to the script.  The unset function eliminated it for the remaining execution of that script, but a refresh is a fresh execution.

You could simply re-direct the browser to the entry pageafter doing your insert, that way a subsequent refresh will be safe.

```
//INSERT INTO DB
//...
header('Location: samepage.php');
exit();
```

I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this as well.

Comment: please see my comment at Johann du Toit

Comment: @sof_user I'd have to say please see the first part of my answer.  unset()'ing $_POST has absolutely no connection to a refresh.  Refreshing would cause the browser to call the page and generate a fresh populated $_POST all over again.  Please add a redirection like I've suggested.

Comment: i think ,  javascript window.location="somepage " is much comfortable than header('location:somepage.php')

Comment: What if someone disable javascript @sof_user

Answer (score 3):

Your approach cannot work, you would just be editing the data that the PHP script has recieved. If the user refreshes the browser then it will submit the same data again, and PHP will populate a fresh new `$_POST` with the data the browser sent.

If you want to stop a refresh resubmitting the data, then use the [POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern](http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/).

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST value will only be removed on the Server-Side Meaning that on that one request PHP will not be able to see or use it (You removed it).

But you are rendering the Submit button on the page's HTML so every time someone visits the page and submit the form they will submit the value again. And you will remove it again for PHP on that current request. So every request would insert the data into the database.

You might want to rather look into rather checking if the record already does exists (OR if the user has one already, not sure what you want) and then redirect them away from the page using `header('Location: otherpage.php');`.

Hope that helps...

Comment: "so every time someone visits the page and submit the form they will submit the value again. " - if anyone clicks on the submit button and submits data, that is no prob. I just want to prevent users from inserting into database the same data whenever they refresh the page after first insertion of data. if unsetting $_POST['vendor_add_submit'] removes its content, then on page refresh (and not on clicking on the submit button again) , how can the same data be inserted into database?